# JSONP ajax callback failing

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I have following script running on my local test drive. It imports a JSON file and builds a webpage, but for some reason, there is an error in handling the data. No data is shown...

But whenever I use (the same) data hard-coded, I get the result I want. So this made me think it has something to do with the way I handle the JSON import...

This is my AJAX callback:

```
getGames: function(fn) {
     $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: App.Config('webserviceurl')+'games-payed.js',
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function (data) {
              console.log('streets', data);
              if(fn){
                  fn(data);
              }
          },
          error: function (msg) {
              if(fn){
                  fn({status:400});
              }
          }
     });
}
```

And this code isn't working, nor am I getting any errors in my console...

When I load the data hard coded, it works perfectly:

```
getGames: function(fn) {
     var games = App.Config('dummyGames');

     if(fn){
          fn(games);
     }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my AJAX callback?

**EDIT:**
The JSON file looks like this:

```
jsonp1({
    "status": "200",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Title 1",
            "publishDate": "2013-03-27T15:25:53.430Z",
            "thumbnail": "images/thumbs/image_game1.png",
            "html5": "http://mysite.com/index.html"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Title 2",
            "publishDate": "2013-03-20T15:25:53.430Z",
            "thumbnail": "images/thumbs/image_game2.png",
            "html5": "http://mysite.com/index.html"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "Title 3",
            "publishDate": "2013-03-18T15:25:53.430Z",
            "thumbnail": "images/thumbs/image_game3.png",
            "html5": "http://mysite.com/index.html"
        }

    ]
});
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the console if you log in the error callback? is "games-payed" a typo? What do you see in the network tab of your browser?

Comment: Can you show us what `games-payed.js` looks like? About _payed_ : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92547/paid-vs-payed tldr; use **paid**

Comment: About the "payed" naming, it's a service we get from our client, so I have no control on the naming :) I've added a snippet of the JSON file.

Comment: I edited to change the question's title to "JSONP ajax callback failing" instead of "JSON ajax callback failing" as this question is more about jsonp. Hope you ok with it

Answer (score 2):

In your example, I see that you wrap your json data inside `jsonp1`. I suppose that is a fixed name. If that's the case, try this:

```
getGames: function(fn) {
     $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: App.Config('webserviceurl')+'games-payed.js',
          jsonp: false,
          jsonpCallback:"jsonp1",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function (data) {
              console.log('streets', data);
              if(fn){
                  fn(data);
              }
          },
          error: function (msg) {
              if(fn){
                  fn({status:400});
              }
          }
     });
}
```

Notice the `jsonpCallback:"jsonp1"` and `jsonp: false`. The reason for this is: by default, jquery will generate the callback function name automatically and randomly and append `?callback=generatedFunctionName` to the end of your url. Thanks to the callback parameter, the code on server side could use the same function name to call the callback on browser.

In your case, you're using **fixed** function name (jsonp1), so you have to:

- Specify your function name explicitly using `jsonpCallback="jsonp1"`
- Set `jsonp = false` to prevent jQuery from adding the "?callback" string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation.